# In nested master pages child master page code behind not working properly

Tags: c#, master-pages

In nested master pages child master pasge code behind not working properly..

if i debug and set a stopper in child master page code behind file its not working..

Following is my code:

**here is main master page html  code**

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="AdminMaster.master.cs"
Inherits="Admin_AdminMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="mainouter">
            <div class="Contents">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**here is the child master page html code**

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin/AdminMaster.master"
AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeFile="AdCommercialDetail.master.cs" Inherits="Admin_AdCommercialDetail" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2"
ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                fdgsdf
            </td>
            <td>
                dfgfdg
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

**code behind of master page**

```cs
public partial class Admin_AdminMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

**code behind of child master page**

```cs
public partial class Admin_AdCommercialDetail :
    System.Web.UI.MasterPage {
    SqlDatabase db = (SqlDatabase)DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("ConnectionString");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Label1.Text = "gfjhfhggggggggggggggggg";
        Label1.Text = "fgdjgjhghklgfsaddffgghhjjkdsdfghjk";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in your child master place the controls outside the ContentPlaceHolder like,

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin/AdminMaster.master"
AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeFile="AdCommercialDetail.master.cs" Inherits="Admin_AdCommercialDetail" %>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                fdgsdf
            </td>
            <td>
                dfgfdg
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: It show Err:::Error 1 Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.

Comment: Problem is found. In Child Master Page AutoEventWireUp is set False By Default and I have Set it to True and Problem Solved.